# Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example from DataFrame

Tags: python

I try to generate a code to provide dataframe examples for stack overflow and the minimal required example.

Ideally I would like to create a small sample from the dataframe involved automaticall and post the sample as code snippet for easy reproduction, like this: df = pd.DataFrame(data=..., columns=...) which works for native datatypes but crashes for non native like shown in the examples below.

Is there a way to prevent the following error or a smarter way in general?

```
# =============================================================================
# Example 1 - working
# =============================================================================

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"a":[9,0],"b":[3,7],"c":[1,31]})
print(df.to_dict())

df_dict = {'a': {0: 9, 1: 0},
 'b': {0: 3, 1: 7},
 'c': {0: 1, 1: 31}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)

# =============================================================================
# Example 2 - not working
# =============================================================================

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"a":[datetime.now(),0],"b":[3,7],"c":[1,31]})
print(df.to_dict())

df_dict = {'a': {0: datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 31, 12, 47, 14, 864063), 1: 0},
 'b': {0: 3, 1: 7},
 'c': {0: 1, 1: 31}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
```

**AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'**

Comment: Try replacing datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 31, 12, 47, 14, 864063) with datetime(2020, 5, 31, 12, 47, 14, 864063)

Comment: @Anshul, thank you it works, but Id like to get the corresponding code without manual adjustments like this.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. It was not a manual adjustment. It was incorrect reference in your code that got fixed.

Comment: AFAIK, the easiest way to produce example dataframes is by using read_clipboard method. It works well with copy pastable source dataset for any df. You can search more about it.

Comment: you get error because you incorrectly use imported module `datetime` - if you use `from datetime import datetime` then you need `datetime(...)`. To use `datetime.datetime(...)` you would have to use `import datetime` (without `from datetime`).